# Would events with no listeners have a sizeable impact on performance?

Tags: c#, .net, events

Considering the following basic event-related code inside a class:

```
public event EventHandler Updated;

public void OnUpdated() {
    if (Updated != null) Updated(sender: this, e: null)
}
```

If no one has subscribed to the Updated event, I would not like the fourth line to cause any significant performance drag (the idea is to let subscribers choose the most fine-grained events to subscribe to have only the minimal number of events fired and prevent a message queue overload).

Should I care and track the existence of subscribers (e.g. with `if (Updated != null && OnUpdateSubscribed) Updated(sender: this, e: null)` or trust the compiler/runtime?

Comment: Of all the things that can cause performance drag, I would put this near the bottom of the, (very long), list.  Off-hand, I can't think of any real apps where this could significantly affect overall performance.  As Marc says, there's not much you can do about it anyway.

Comment: I am talking about an app where you would otherwise have thousands of events fired per second, this is why it could add up to something...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The check `OnUpdate != null` **defines** an event being subscribed / unsubscribed. In fact, there is no real difference between a boolean check and a null check, because ultimately both of them are just a "load field", "branch if false" - because a null reference counts as "false" as far as logic checks are concerned.

My only suggestion would be: store it in a local variable, to prevent a (pretty unlikely, but possible) race condition:

```
var snapshot = Updated;
if(snapshot != null) snapshot(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

So: no, basically: there is no overhead of this.

Example:

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
protected virtual void OnSomeEvent()
{
    var snapshot = SomeEvent;
    if (snapshot != null) snapshot(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Compiles to (comments are mine):

```
.method family hidebysig newslot virtual instance void OnSomeEvent() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 3
    .locals init (
        [0] class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler snapshot)

    // var snapshot = SomeEvent
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler Foo::SomeEvent
    L_0006: stloc.0

    // if(snapshot == null) goto L_0016;
    L_0007: ldloc.0 
    L_0008: brfalse.s L_0016

    // snapshot(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    L_000a: ldloc.0 
    L_000b: ldarg.0 
    L_000c: ldsfld class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs [mscorlib]System.EventArgs::Empty
    L_0011: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.EventHandler::Invoke(object, class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs)

    // L_0016: return;
    L_0016: ret 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you confirm that the following extension prevents this race condition?: 
public static void Raise(this EventHandler handler, object sender, EventArgs args) {
            if (handler != null) handler(sender, args);
        }

Comment: @ErwinMayer that should be fine too, and again: no significant overhead (esp. since static call). It *does* do a few extra "load"s, but: nothing to get excited about.